# Whats the best way generate a table of the top N drawdowns in a return index with python?

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAorA.png)

I have a time series with stock market returns, dates, and an index that starts at 100 based on the returns. Example data below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU2xF.png)

I am trying to get a table output that shows the top N drawdowns in a time series, the date range for each drawdown, and the duration. I have a working script for this, but it's very messy and the accuracy is off at times.

```
df['drawdown'] = df['index_100'] / df['index_100'].expanding().max() - 1

throw_away_df = df[df['drawdown'] == 0].copy()
throw_away_df = throw_away_df[['Date']]
throw_away_df['duration'] = throw_away_df['Date'].diff().dt.days
throw_away_df['start_date'] = throw_away_df['Date'].shift(1)
throw_away_df = throw_away_df[throw_away_df['duration'] > 35]
throw_away_df['rank'] = throw_away_df['duration'].rank(ascending=False)
throw_away_df['drawdown'] = 0
throw_away_df = throw_away_df.reset_index(drop=True)

for i in throw_away_df.index:
    x = max(abs(df['drawdown'][(df['Date'] > throw_away_df['start_date'].loc[i]) & (df['Date'] < throw_away_df['Date'].loc[i])]))
    throw_away_df['drawdown'].loc[i] = -x


throw_away_df = throw_away_df[throw_away_df['rank'] <= N]
throw_away_df = throw_away_df.sort_values(by=['rank'])
throw_away_df = throw_away_df[['start_date', 'Date', 'duration', 'drawdown']]
throw_away_df.columns = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'duration', 'drawdown']
```

Here's the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJsj.png)

Comment: Is the output generated by your code or the desired one? Can you please provide the other.

Comment: Yes, the current output is the desired. The third image (table) is the  desired output.